# Return File in net Core is corrupted when using FileStreamResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a method that returns a FileStreamResult to download a file created by NPOI, an Excel file. In the method i use a sample to save locally the file in wwwroot with FileStream and it works, but when i need to return the file and download in front end, the file  downloaded is corrupted.
The file is open, and contains the columns that i write.
The file created locally is open normally.

This is the method:

```
public IActionResult DescargarRepEstacion()
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
    return StatusCode(400, ModelState);
  }
  try
  {
    var fullPath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Formatos", "Formato Estacion.xls");
    var workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    var sheet = workBook.CreateSheet("Formato Estación");
    var rowIndex = 0;
    var row = sheet.CreateRow(rowIndex);
    row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("ID");
    row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("DESTINO");
    row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("PERMISO");
    row.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("TERMINAL");
    rowIndex++;
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    workBook.Write(ms);
    using (var file = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create)) {
      workBook.Write(file);
    }
    ms.Position = 0;

      return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    return StatusCode(500, ex.Message.ToString());
  }
}
```

In the front end:

```
    axios.get("Formatos/DescargarEstacion", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept':'application/vnd.ms-excel',
      }
    }).then(response => {
      this.loadingDownloadEstacion = false;
      download(response.data, 'Formato Estacion.xls');
      console.log(response.data);
   //   const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
   //   const link = document.createElement('a');
   //   link.href = url;
   //   link.setAttribute('download', 'Formato Estaciones.xls');
   //   document.body.appendChild(link);
   //   link.click();
    }).catch(error => {
      this.loadingDownloadEstacion = false;
      console.log(error.response);
      this.snackbar = true;
      this.textSnackbar = error.response.data;
    })
```

What am i doing wrong?

UPDATE WHIT SCREENSHOT:
[image]

Comment: Might be worth added the HTTP header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myexcelfile.xls`

Comment: @SteveJ i added the Content-Disposition but is the same corrupted file :/

Comment: Can you say how it is corrupted? Maybe post a screenshot or describe what is incorrect about the file.

Comment: @SteveJ i update the post

Comment: Hmm, the code looks fine. Can you download the file with something other than axios to test it? Fiddler or something maybe?

Comment: Define your memory stream outside the try block like  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

Comment: I had some issues when my files had spaces and accents

Comment: @SteveJ in Postman shows the same that the Excel file...

Comment: @IsaíasOrozcoToledo The same as in still corrupted?

Comment: @SteveJ yeah, the same corrupted content

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to use the other constructor on the FileStreamResult class and play with properies on the MediaTypeHeaderValue such as Charset, Encoding and MediaType.